# Help! I got a runaway PHP script. My server is down

Tags: php, infinite-loop

I got a PHP script that is looping and will continue to do so for about another hour. How do I stop it. The script explicitly overrides the time out and the memory buffer. It's on a shared hosting server with cPanel installed. The entire website is down until the script completes.

I had added a `usleep(100000)` statement, but it doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the server admin in the first place?

Comment: Email support. They might get back to me before we go extinct.

Comment: That was a hit in the 90s wasn't it? *♫♪ Runaway script, never coming back, runaway on a server rack. I had hoped that you would timeout someday, but you're still eating up memory ♫♪* :)

Comment: One man's misery, is another man's song!

Comment: Ask your server admin to kill the process. You can probably do it yourself by logging into the box, then ps -Af, then find the process id then kill -9 process_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible untile you ask to server admin to kill this routine. More over, please avoid to use sleep(), usleep() functions in your php. Php has a limitations to execute those functions when it is in Apache server and Linux OS.

If you want to make delays using php go with date-time functions... see code below

`StrCp_Time = Now()
Difference = DateDiff("s",Session("submittime"), StrCp_Time) '// Difference Between Two Dates(Seconds , LastSubmitTime , CurrentTime)
If Difference > 10 Then '// 10 seconds`

... Submit Form ...

End If
Session("submittime") = StrCp_Time

Answer (score 2):

If the script already runs you can't do anything except killing the process/webserver/host and restarting it.

Answer (score 1):

First contact your host and ask them to kill the process. This is the best and simple way.

Answer (score 0):

Think the moral is, never override them, just lift them up to a higher level.

Comment: It's a crawler. I don't want it stopping any soon.

Comment: You could lift the execution time to a nicer level (3 hours or something), then end and restart the process when it finishes a job within a certain time from that.